# BASH: need to get output from a command, store the nth column in a variable, then parse it

Tags: bash

I need to parse through the nth column of a command's output - this output is guaranteed to be a table of some sort, with undefined length and width. This table also has a header that I would like to ignore. I am thinking of doing this by storing the desired column in a variable and then parsing it.

Additionally, if I wanted to do this same thing but only parse through the values that contain a certain pattern, how would I do this? I would have to `pipe` the output of the command above into `grep`, and then store the output of that into the array I parse over.

**Sample Input and Output**:

```
~$ myCommand <args>
TABLE HEADER: <Some explanation of what the table means>
first_cola second_cola third_cola fourth_cola ...
first_colb second_colb third_colb fourth_colb ...
first_colc second_colc third_colc fourth_colc ...
...        ...         ...        ...
```

here "first_cola", etc, are strings. So I'd need to, for example, iterate through all "first_col" values, and maybe only look at the ones that have a certain pattern.

**Clarification:**
The User selects which *column* to look at by inputting a number from 1 to the number of columns in the table and, after that, has the option of selecting some values *from the column previously selected* by only selecting the values that match a certain pattern. These values should be saved to an array that I will then iterate over. The operation that is then done on the values selected should not be relevant to this question.

Comment: The answer to this question will almost certainly involve `awk` or `perl` or similar. Show us exact input and output.

Comment: @EtanReisner Hopefully that sample works, despite being generic.

Comment: What do you need to do with these values? Do you only care about the single column in your chosen rows? Or all columns? How are you going to select the rows/fields you want?

Comment: @EtanReisner I only care about one column. And then, once I'm looking at that column, I sometimes only care about the values that "contain" a certain pattern. I want to store these in an array so I can then iterate through them and do something else with each value.

Comment: Define "do something"? And how you select the values you care about (pattern matching, something else)?

Comment: The question is still very vague. I think you need to delete sentences such as "I know how to iterate over arrays in BASH". Stop speculating over *how* to solve the problem ("arrays", "iterate", "BASH") and just give a really clear example of the kind of problem you are trying to solve.  E.g. *"I want to find all the rows from the file where the 5th column is entirely made of digits, and I simply want to print all those rows to stdout"*

Comment: let's say the column is selected by the user inputting a number from 1 to n, where n is the number of columns the table has. And the user also has the ability to, within the selected column, select only the values that match a certain pattern. Then there will be a `for` loop over those values where some other operation that is not relevant here will be done on each of the selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a number of rows to skip (either 0 or 1 normally) and the column required, then you could get the unfiltered output with:

```
myCommand '<args>' |
awk -v skip=1 -v column=4 'NR <= skip { next } { print $column }'
```

If you want to filter too, you can add a `grep` after the `awk` command, or you can have `awk` do the filtering too:

```
myCommand '<args>' |
awk -v skip=1 -v column=4 filter='[a-z]$' \
    'NR <= skip { next } { if ($column ~ filter) print $column }'
```

That filters column 4 (only) for values that end with a lower-case alphabetic character.  You could filter on the whole line by changing the `if` condition to `($0 ~ filter)`.

With a bit more work (quite a bit more work), you could arrange to print sets of columns.  You could arrange to handle all that in one flexible script (I have one, though it doesn't support the regex filtering too).

The standard `cut` command is not flexible about multiple delimiters between columns, unlike `awk`.  Sometimes that's an advantage; sometimes that's a disadvantage.

> Could you explain what `'NR <= skip { next } { print $column }'` does?

The `NR <= skip { next }` part compares the current record number, `NR` with the value in the variable `skip`; if the current record number is less than or equal to the number to skip, then it does a `next` which means skip to the next input record (don't execute anything after it in the script).

The `{ print $column }` part has an empty pattern (or condition), so it is 'always' executed.  It prints the data from the column specified by the number in the variable `column`.

The variables `skip` and `column` are set on the command line by `-v skip=1 -v column=4`.

Comment: Could you explain what `'NR <= skip { next } { print $column }'` does?

Answer (score 1):

`egrep '2$' < <(echo -e 'ha hb hc\na1 b1 c1\na2 b2 c2' | tail -n+2 | cut -d' ' -f2)`

- `echo -e 'ha hb hc\na1 b1 c1\na2 b2 c2'` prints sample 3x3 grid
- `tail -n+2` drops the first line, the header
- `cut -d' ' -f2` is cutting the second column using space as a delimiter
- `egrep '2$' < <(xxx)` searches strings ending with `2` in the output of the command `xxx`

Comment: Why is there a "$" in `egrep '2$' < <(xxx)`.